# NetBeans: Test-unit gem not found, falling back to default test-unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I've been experiencing a problem running unit tests in **NetBeans 6.9.1**.

> rake test::unit
>
> Test-unit gem not found, falling back
> to default test-unit
> ...

The problem is not a showstopper, because after that message all the tests run and I can see the results. I am just curious what might be wrong with my development environment. When I run my unit tests from command line that message doesn't appear.

My platform is:

Windows 7 x64

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i386-mingw32]

Rails 2.3.8

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools/Ruby Gems and see if the test-unit gem is or isn't installed.  Even after I installed NetBeans and got the updates the test-unit gem was not included.  I had to download it(new gems).  If your install shows that you have test-unit the only other thing I can think of is to try un-installing it and re-installing it.  Good luck.

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 (Build 201007282301)
Java: 1.6.0_20; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 19.0-b09
System: Linux version 2.6.35-25-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)

Comment: I hit this same issue with the NetBeans Ruby tutorial. Realized they said Rails was a prereq and I hadn't installed that (shouldn't need it for just doing Ruby work). Wasn't able to use NB's new gems (permissions issue with NB's dirs) so went to command-line and did `gem install test-unit` and then tests ran.